# How to implement Authorize.Net SDK in iOS

Tags: ios, payment-gateway, authorize.net

In my project i need to  implement payment gateway so that i tried to implement through   Authorize.Net iOS SDK .

By googling i have followed some steps as in below

1)Downloaded Authorize.Net iOS SDK from https://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/ios/

2) Goto MyProject -> Targets -> Build Settings.

**1.Header Search Paths :**

${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2

Mark the Recursive checkbox as checked

$(SRCROOT)/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/ANMobilePaymentLib

**Library Search Paths :**
$(SRCROOT)/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/ANMobilePaymentLib

**Other Linker Flags :**
-lxml2

3) Imported SystemConfiguration.framework

4) Imported libxml2.2.dylib and libxml2dylib

3) Drag and drop the ANMobilePaymentLib.xcodeproj file from   Authorize.Net SDK  folder  into Xcode under MyProject.

**Error :**    (while compiling)

'MobileDeviceLoginRequest.h' file not found

// Here i can't access the header folder

4 ) So that i have tried to add the sdk into my project like a framework , then i got different error

**Error :**  (while compiling)

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/sathish/Documents/CompanyApps/TestApps/PaymentGateway/anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1/ANMobilePaymentLib'

// Here i can't find the ANMobilePaymentLib in Authorize.Net iOS SDK and where i can download LibANMobilePaymentLib.a

pls guide me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created [this sample project](https://github.com/sibahota059/AuthorizeNetPaymentTest/tree/master), you can download from below link : https://github.com/sibahota059/AuthorizeNetPaymentTest/tree/master. This sample only can be compiled and run without any error. you need to add your code to other stuffs.

For Swift, follow [this](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sdk-ios) SDK

Comment: I want to add(just drag & drop anet_ios_sdk-1.1.1) into my project but it always giving error that "ANMobilePaymentLib" library not found..

Comment: hi,
you have to add the framework By --> Target--> Build Phases--> Link Binary with Libraries--> add Other (Now show the path of ANMobilePaymentLib)

Comment: How the swipe work in this demo? any idea about that?. i try to swipe card with IDTECH swiper but nothing happen. if any successfully implemented then pls guide me. thanks.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota any skd available for swift?