# Working with authorize.net Payment Gateway For iOS

Tags: ios, authorize.net

I have downloaded the SDK from  [authorize.net](http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/ios/)

And i finished all given steps but when i even though also its giving me error[image]

So i found Because i have .a file and because of that i am getting error so am i right for that ?

[image: libANMobilePaymentLib.a]

Does any one is having libANMobilePaymentLib.a or How can i get that ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/19818299/2106973

Answer (score 0):

Do all three of these:

1. Set your Other Linker Flags with `-lxml2` to allow for xml parsing.
2. Set your Header Search Paths with the path that contains `libxml2` header files. (ex. `/usr/include/libxml2` with recursive checked).
3. Target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Library, click the plus sign and add `libxml2.dylib`
   [image: Screenshot]